# getting the index of a Seq / Vector while in a map function

Tags: scala

I have a Seq[Article]

I want to map over them but somehow get access to the position of the Article in the Sequence.

So if the Seq contains (Article1, Article2, Article3, Article4) I want to do something like this:

```
mySeq.map { article =>

   val index = article.getPositionInSeq  // <- obviously this is not defined

   //if index odd {}
   //if index even {}

}
```

I know that Vector is indexed, and has a indices function defined on it which gives the range of the Vector (in my case, 0..3) but how could I get the actual place for each Article in the Sequence? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use zipWithIndex to transform sequence of elements into sequence of pairs (element, index):

```
mySeq.zipWithIndex.map { e =>
  val (element, idx) = (e._1, e._2)
}
```

Comment: You can directly do `mySeq.zipWithIndex.map { case (element, idx) =>`

Comment: Thanks to both. Makes it look so easy!